# Display docx files from document library as html

Tags: 2013, document-library, document, html

I need to display three documents as html in one page.
Also, these html page should always show the latest version of documents.
The page should work on all browsers.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to convert these document to MHTML format using Word Automation Services in Event Receiver (I used ItemUpdated and ItemAdded events).

I'm going to implement feature with application page and show created mhtml pages in frames.

*Is this a good solution? Are there better solution?*

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the Office Web Apps to view the documents?  Then you wouldnt need to convert them and potentially lose fidelity.

You can embed the word web app in an IFrame and use the WOPIFrame URL to display the document.

See here for an example of getting the URL to WOPIFrame.aspx that you will need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026281/how-to-construct-get-office-web-app-url-for-sharepoint-documents

Answer (score 1):

Use  [Page Viewer Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx) and then modify webpart's properties and add link to document you want to display.

Here's detailed instructions

[How to Insert a Web Page onto a Site Using the Page Viewer Web Part for SharePoint 2013](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/07/30/how-to-insert-a-web-page-onto-a-site-using-the-page-viewer-web-part-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: could you please help me with format of the link to a file? I tried to use link to a file in sharepoint: `http://sp2013-dev-01:1313/Documents/test_document.docx` and such link to a file: `file://sp2013-dev-01:1313/Documents/test_document.docx`. But they doesn't work. And I receive in Page Viewer Tool Pane such message: "The path to the folder is not valid for the Link property. Check the spelling and syntax, and then type a valid path.". How can I use a document from a document library?

Comment: For testing, I created empty Web Site with a virtual folder in which was my docx file (http://goo.gl/7T78A6). Then I inserted address of the file: `http://11.11.11.11/c/test_document.docx`. Sharepoint admitted such address. But now in Page Viewer web Part on the page I see only empty space. No any content from my docx file. What could be the problem?

Comment: In which browser are you testing it and did you tried "test link" after populating link property ?

Comment: Just tried "test link" with link `http://11.11.11.11/c/test_document.docx`. It can't find the file. I use IE and Chrome.

Comment: Webpart will only work on IE, you will need to find exact document's URL you can do so by navigating to document library and check the properties of document.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't fit me. The page should work on all browsers. Please review an update of my question.

Comment: The `Page Viewer Web Part` is blurry for us when displaying a PDF - any ideas?